# Electron(v5-v7) webview not accepting the keystrokes

Tags: events, webview, electron, textfield, keystroke

I'm writing the app with Electron and now I'm facing the issue with the webview.

I have some webview in which there are a few text fields and one dropdown. And text fields are not working when I'm trying to tap some characters in input but the dropdown handles the **up** and **down** arrows. Also, I saw really interesting behavior: the text field's keystrokes started working when I tapped on the **TAB** button a few times.

I used Electron v3 and v4 and those versions don't have that bug but they are not feasible for me.

Someone had that issue before?